# How can I narrow down App audience?

Tags: permissions, app, audience-targeting, provider-hosted-app

I have developed an provider hosted app and I want to run it on an internal on-premise Farm.

When I have published my App into the app catalog, is it possible to just install it on one Site? So not everyone who can add an app can see my app?

Can I use something like audience targeting in my app catalog?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you want app to be installed only on one site. By default once the app is added to the catalog is available everywhere. The quick and dirty way is to add to the catalog add to the desired site then un-check "Enabled" in the app catalog. This will prevent it from being available for adding to any other site (you could write a script to do this for you). If you are making updates to the app you will need to check Enable for the app update on the site where you installed it and then uncheck the Enable again. It is dirty way but might allow you to accomplish what you are looking for.